# How to make hyperlinks point to the top of an equation?

Tags: equations, hyperref

I've got a system of equation splitted on multiple lines with the environment `split` and a reference to them, which I would like to point to the top of the system of equations. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{mylabel}
    \begin{split}
    \tau y + \nabla \phi(x)=0 \\
    D^{-1} y - x=0 \\
    y^T x \leq 1
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}

    The conditions \eqref{mylabel}...
\end{document}
```

However, when I click on the hyperlink in the PDF output file, it directs me to the middle of the equation, rather than pointig to the top of it.

I already know the package `hypcap`, but it only works within floating environments...

Comment: eqref links to the equation number. Do you also want to shift it to the first line or do you want to keep it vertically centered?

Comment: I would like it to point to the first line of the equation: keeping it vertically centered means that the reader, after clicking on the link, sees only the second and the third line, and has to scroll the page up to read the first one too.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is to put the `\refstepcounter` inside the equation, as long as the `\lable` comes BEFORE the `\tag`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]%
  {\hbox{\refstepcounter{equation}\label{mylabel}}}%
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    \tau y + \nabla \phi(x)=0 \\
    D^{-1} y - x=0 \\
    y^T x \leq 1
    \end{split}\tag{\theequation}
    \end{equation*}

    The conditions \eqref{mylabel}...
\end{document}
```

The hyperref version of `\refstepcounter` places a `\hypertarget` at that location.  The hyperref version of  `\label` saves the value of the last counter incremented by `\refstepcounter` along with `\thepage`, `\@currentlabel` and `\@currentHref`.  `\tag` uses a user supplied equation number, and the equation counter is not incremented (or both incremented and decremented).

Comment: Nice solution, thank you! Can you explain better how did you do it and what do the commands you added do?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think you missed the `*`. It should be `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`.

Comment: @Benjamin - You are right. Even with the \tag a \hypertarget {equation.0.2} would be created by the first equation.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: your answer is almost perfect now, but doing this way the pointer brings the PDF viewer to the line _before_ the equation, and not exactly on the first line of the equation, like [here](http://imgur.com/K5jximu).